# Is caching file reading speeds up processing?

Tags: php, performance, file, caching, optimization

I have a code reading and processing few millions of lines from a file that still runs longer than I would like.

Here is the main loop:

```
while( $hash = $this->readLineFromFile($table) ) {
     $hash = $this->process($hash);
     if ($hash) $this->store($table, $hash);         
}
```

So every loop reads a line from the file (on a hard disk), processes it, and stores in memory.

My questions:

1. Is it worth the effort, to speed up the code, to read several lines at once into memory and then process them?
2. If yes, how to identify the best number of lines to be read at once?
3. Is there a fast convenience method in PHP to read specified number of lines from a file?

UPDATE.

Following Eugen Rieck' suggestion I will use

```
$result = file_get_contents($file, null, null, $offset, $maxlen);
$array = explode('\n', $result);
```

and then iterate over `$array` except when reaching the last array entry, in which case I need to repeat the reading into `$arrayNew`, glue last entry from `$array` with first from `$arrayNew`, process it, then continue processing the rest of `$arrayNew` etc.

Feels a bit hacky to me, anyone knows a good code example doing that?

Comment: Have you checked, that you are really disk bound? E.g. test from a ramdisk

Comment: @EugenRieck Based on http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment/#local_disk_space_per_worker I was assuming it. It also runs slower there than from my local SDD. Is there a simple way to check it?

Comment: If you're reading the whole file anyway, you may just try [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Comment: @Passerby The file is massive - almost 500MB, but I only have 300MB available. So can't read it all at once. I have to process and compress it line by line, then I can store it.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Then you're reading the whole file anyway: cache or not, you'll still need to `readLineFromFile()` that many times. I doubt if there will be any real benefit.

Comment: @Passerby I could change `readLineFromFile()` to read from the cache instead.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I meant you still need to read that many lines from the file -- still need to execute "read a line from the file" that many times.

Comment: Try to `fread()` into chunks of ca. 20-100MB, then process!

Comment: @EugenRieck Great idea! They mention that `file_get_contents()` "has much better performance" - is it worth trying instead?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` reads the whole file into RAM - not an option for you!

Comment: @EugenRieck It has options to specify `offset` and `maxlen`!

Comment: Ah! You have quite a new PHP at your disposal - go for it, but mind, that the average hoster out there might have the older version, that reads the whole file.

Comment: I see, offset ant maxlen came with 5.1.0, so you are on the safe side.

Comment: @EugenRieck Have spent hours on programming and testing only to find out that now it takes longer! What a disappointment!